# LINQ To SQL: Setting READ UNCOMMITTED isolation globally on querying

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

My application does CRUD operations on SQL Server database using LINQ. For read operations, it is okay to do dirty reads. Instead of setting TransactionScope on each read method, is there a global way to set dirty reads for reads without messing up write operations? Note that there are hundreds of read methods doing join across multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as described on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ialonso/archive/2012/11/26/how-to-set-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-server-wide.aspx) blog, there isn't a supported way to do this. You'll have to do it for each transaction.